# Copy and past loop from excel to word coming up with Command Error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have this Code running to select cells from Excel between 2 cells defined in my Code and then paste it into word at the Location of a specific bookmark. However when ever I run the Code it works for the first cells between "start_of_text", "end_of_text" and "Start_of_table", "End_of_table" but then i get an error on the second textemarke.pastespecial (xlPasteall) saying run time error '4198' Command Failed.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
  Dim rownum As Integer
  Dim colnum As Integer
  Dim startrow As Integer
  Dim endrow As Integer
  Dim textmarke

   rownum = 1
   colnum = 2

 ' Filtering for T1 line

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte").Columns("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=<T1 Line>" _
    , Operator:=xlOr


   ' Find eveything between start of text and end of text
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte")
    For rownum = 1 To 10000
       Do
         If .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "Start_of_text" Then
             startrow = rownum + 1
          End If
          rownum = rownum + 1

       If (rownum > 10000) Then Exit For

       Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "End_of_text"
       endrow = rownum - 1

       'Select everything from start of text to end of text
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte").Range("B" & startrow & ":B" & endrow).Copy

       'Paste description from excel sheet
       Set textmarke = doc.Bookmarks("INSERT_T1_LINE_reference_TABLE").Range
       textmarke.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
       textmarke.Style = "Heading 4"
       doc.Bookmarks.Add "INSERT_T1_LINE_reference_TABLE", textmarke 'Set the text marker on this specific range.

    ' Find everything between start of table and end of table
       Do
          If .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "Start_of_table" Then
             startrow = rownum + 1
          End If
          rownum = rownum + 1

       If (rownum > 10000) Then Exit For

       Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 2).Value = "End_of_table"
       endrow = rownum - 1

      'Select everything from start of table to end of table
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template-Referenz-Produkte").Range("B" & startrow & ":E" & endrow).Copy

       'Paste description from excel sheet
       Set textmarke = doc.Bookmarks("INSERT_T1_LINE_reference_TABLE").Range
       textmarke.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
       doc.Bookmarks.Add "INSERT_T1_LINE_reference_TABLE", textmarke 'Set the text marker on this specific range.

    Next rownum
    End With
```

Comment: I am not sure of this error, but why are you pasting to the same `Bookmark`? The loops also seem redundant, as first loop copies Column B, while second loop copies Columns B:E.  Can you explain why both are necessary?

Comment: I am doing this as I want to Format the first paste as a heading and the second as a table and didnt know any other way to do this. With the bookmark I am doing this as I am not sure how many tables will be pasted in and thought by adding a new bookmark bellow with the same Name was the easiest method.

Comment: Have you tried the answer I suggested below? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `textMarke.PasteSpecial` you may try:

```
textMarke.Select
doc.Parent.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
```

Comment: I tried this solution however it pastes the tables inside of each other instead of bellow as instructed to.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: well, I think you need a different Bookmark fir each table. as in the code you  provided, it only looks at 1 name bookmark. or, you need some other solution to paste 1st table at  bookmark, and any subsequent table assign a different Word Range (NOT the bookmark).

Comment: But the bookmark should be deleted when I replace it with my data so therefore when I add the bookmark again it should be the only one.

Comment: Yes, it is, but this is what's happening: you're using the bookmark to paste the first table, that's all good. But then you're assigning a bookmark to the *exact same Range* (containing the pasted table) for next, and subsequent iterations. You need to adjust/increment the range to the next line in the document, I think.